# How do you separate superimposed folders on desktop page?

Tags: desktop

I recently upgraded my macbook pro with OS X El capitan.  In the top Right hand corner of my desktop page I have 2 superimposed folders.  How do you separate them? I've tried dragging one folder to another part of the desktop page but it will not stay there.

Comment: If you right-click the Desktop, can you change the "Sort by" to none?

Comment: I will post that as an answer, then!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right-click on the Desktop. Go down to "Sort by" and change it to "none." That should allow you to move the files wherever you want.